# Force a specific overload when template<typename, value...>

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

This question follows : [Force a specific overload when template template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13910355/882932)

Consider the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

// Version A
template<typename T>
void f(const T& x)
{
    std::cout<<"Version A"<<std::endl;
}

// Version B
template<typename... T1, template<typename...> class T>
void f(const T<T1...>& x)
{
    std::cout<<"Version B"<<std::endl;
}

// Version C
template<typename T1, typename TN, template<typename, TN...> class T, TN... N>
void f(const T<T1, N...>& x)
{
    std::cout<<"Version C"<<std::endl;
}

// Main
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    f(double());
    f(std::vector<double>());
    f(std::array<double, 3>()); // <- How to force the use of Version C ?
    return 0;
}
```

By default, it will produce (with GCC 4.7.1) :

```
Version A
Version B
Version A
```

How to force the use of `Version C` when the passed type is a template with the good shape (I can add new versions of `f`, I can add `std::enable_if` or other C++11 type traits syntax, but if possible I would like to avoid adding an helper class) ?

Note : The trick should work for every integral type TN...

Comment: I doubt it's possible. Why do you want to do this anyways?

Comment: Have you tried calling `f<double, std::size_t, std::array, 3>(std::array<double, 3>{ })`? Note that you're making a vexing-parse mistake.

Comment: If you change that to this : `template<typename T, size_t ...N, template<typename, size_t ...> class C> void f(const C<T, N...>& x) {}`, then it works.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I don't think it is a vexing-parse mistake here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't deduce the type of a non-type template argument in template argument deduction.  This is explicitly stated in the standard:

> #### 14.8.2.5 Deducing template arguments from a type [temp.deduct.type]
>
> 13 - A template type argument cannot be deduced from the type of a non-type template-argument.
> 14 - [Example:
>
> ```
> template<class T, T i> void f(double a[10][i]);
> int v[10][20];
> f(v); // error: argument for template-parameter T cannot be deduced
> ```
>
> — end example ]

This works:

```
// Version C
template<typename T1, template<typename, size_t...> class T, size_t... N>
void f(const T<T1, N...>&) {
    std::cout<<"Version C"<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: No, you can. [Compilers that don’t do it are buggy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/472750/1968).

Comment: @KonradRudolph that's different; `TSize` is deduced from the array element type.